# Fixed size right panel, fluid left and semantic element order

Tags: html, css

On a portion of a web site I have a container which contains two blocks. One panel that has a static width and a left panel that should fill the space to the left of the right panel. I have solved it today by having the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="rightpanel"></div>
   <div class="leftpanel"></div>
</div>

.leftpanel {
overflow:hidden;
}

.rightpanel{
width: 200px;
float: right;
}
```

The problem here is that I need to declare the rightpanel before the leftpanel. I would like to be able to declare it like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="leftpanel"></div>
   <div class="rightpanel"></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on what I should do? Help gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the element being floated, then set the width of the flexibly sized element to that of the page minus the known width of the sidebar, by using `calc`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/taL3fhc8/)

Change your CSS to:

```
.leftpanel {
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 200px)
}
.rightpanel {
    width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention one important thing in the question, and that is that I want the left panel to be unaware of the right panel. This view normally has a right panel, but not always. I would like the left panel to take all available space in that case.